# Response from Slack message Menu with DialogFlow

Tags: dialogflow-es, slack-api

I have developped a chat bot using Slack + Dialogflow + a back in nodeJS, and I'm able to send and receive message from the user. I can also use buttons without any problem.
But when I create a message menus with dynamique options, and I select one of them, I get the following message : "Empty data received on Action Endpoint".

The JSON used to create the message menus is from the slack documentation.
None of the value should hit a known intent, so i'm expecting something like "Sorry I don't understand" from the failback intent.

```js
{
        "payload": {
            "slack":
                {
                    "text": "Would you like to play a game?",
                    "response_type": "in_channel",
                    "attachments": [
                        {
                            "text": "Choose a game to play",
                            "fallback": "If you could read this message, you'd be choosing something fun to do right now.",
                            "color": "#3AA3E3",
                            "attachment_type": "default",
                            "callback_id": "game_selection",
                            "actions": [
                                {
                                    "name": "games_list",
                                    "text": "Pick a game...",
                                    "type": "select",
                                    "options": [
                                        {
                                            "text": "Hearts",
                                            "value": "hearts"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "text": "Bridge",
                                            "value": "bridge"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "text": "Checkers",
                                            "value": "checkers"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "text": "Chess",
                                            "value": "chess"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "text": "Poker",
                                            "value": "poker"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "text": "Falken's Maze",
                                            "value": "maze"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "text": "Global Thermonuclear War",
                                            "value": "war"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
        }
    }
```

I do not understand why the selected option is not send to Dialogflow and I don't know what I'm missing.
Note that I can't find the response in the dialogflow history.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you show your intent and the code to handle it?

Comment: I can, but the problem is that the response doesn't go to an intent (either one of mine or the faillure one). I'll update my question with the JSON that I use to create the message menu if that can help.

Comment: I get an answer from the Dialogflow support, it's just not supported yet.

Comment: @RomainHuber would be awesome if you could put the solution as answer to the question. That would make it much easier for others to find it. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After contacting both Slack and Dialogflow support, this functionnality is not supported by Dialogflow yet.
I found a solution by adding a middleware between Slack and Dialogflow, which takes care of message menus and sends the other messages to Dialogflow.

Comment: Hi! I know it's been a while, but what was your solution? Thanks!

Comment: I don't remember exactly the solution, but if I remember we have a specific route for messages menu and we don't send them to Dialogflow. Not really the best option but it's easy to handle message menu because it's just a list, no need for interpretation